# Convert word or Html to PDF without using Itext

Tags: itext, pdfbox

Hi I have an requirement to convert word or html to PDF without using Itext. I have tired with PDFBox but i couldn't able to achieve since my document or html contains text, tables and images and in PDFBox i can scan and check if the object is type of text, tables and images but couldn't organize into the PDF and getting format issues. can help to share some samples.